# WorkManager stopped status

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I have a WorkManager that I use to sync my data. I'm sending both a `PeriodicWorkRequest` and a `OneTimeWorkRequest` to Worker. But when I send OneTimeWorkRequest, the status of SystemJobService appears to be stopped. This way work manager works fine but I don't know if it's correct to show as `stopped`.

Background Task Inspector looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneTimeWorkRequest and PeriodicWorkRequest have different state logic.

As you saw, once a OneTimeWorkRequest is completed with a Success, Failure or Cancellation. It is marked as stopped.

[WorkManager's documentation covers this topic](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation#one-time_work_states).

For PeriodicWorkRequest, the only way to stop it, is a Cancellation. A Success or Failuire, simply re-enqueue the WorkRequest.

Comment: Then it's not a problem for me to experience this situation. Everything works as it should, right?

Comment: "Everything works" is a bit generic. For OneTimeWorkRequest it is normal that, once they are completed, (success, failure or cancelled) they are marked as stopped and removed from WorkManager's db after a default time interval (that can be configured with https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#keepResultsForAtLeast(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))